# Fix toolbar at the top while pressing enter in EditText in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-toolbar

There is a fragment with an EditText in it, and I want to show a toolbar fixed at the top in this fragment.

I want this toolbar to show up at the top regardless of how many times I press enter on the EditText, but now it just scrolls up and disappears.

How do I solve this?

This is the layout file of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MemoFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/memo_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/memo_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/text_shape"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="top" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried many of solutions found on StackOverflow but couldn't solve it.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: What is "selected_body_part_text_view" in EditText. Make it below Collapsing toolbar layout

Comment: @Parul You can forget about that line, I will just fix the question.

Comment: Have you made the EditText below the Collapsing Toolbar Layout? Is your issue resolved with this?

Comment: If what you mean is inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout, no, it is outside of it.

Comment: No, I mean add this "android:layout_below = "id/collapsing_toolbar" " in Edit Text and give an id "collapsing_toolbar" to CollapsingToolbar

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure? Becoz it is working on my side. Toolbar is fixed and pressing enter in edit text not scrolling the toolbar

Comment: Yeah I am sure, it does not work. Pressing enter still scrolls the toolbar for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you still cannot understand @Parul comments,

here is updated code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MemoFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapseActionView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/memo_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
                android:text="Confirm"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/memo_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/collapseActionView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/text_shape"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="top" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What happened here is you need to define specific locations in Relative layout otherwise later drawn/defined views (your edittext) will be shown above previous drawn views (your toolbar).

Comment: It is working for me, please tell me if your extending your fragment from a custom/modified fragment or using activity toolbar differently?

Comment: I am importing android.support.v4.app.Fragment and I'm sorry I don't get what you mean by using activity toolbar differently

Comment: Does your activity have any toolbar? is your fragment shown on full Activity or on a specific portion? if you could share your java/kotlin side code that would be more easy to understand